# How to move vertices without stretching the texture

Tags: vertices

I am newbie with blender and i am trying to make some ortho-images with blender for MFS2020 game. I have plane model and 2048x2048 png texture attach to it. It looks right. But i want to crop that area more spesific, not just a tile. First i realise bisect tool, that is handy for a while, but if i need to edit that area more spesific than just a line (bisect), i dont know how. I have this sample with 10+ vertices around the model, when im tryin to move those, that texture is stretching. **Can i move those vertices without stretching that texture of mine?**

Image of situation i have: [my situation](https://serving.photos.photobox.com/6082392051cee14de683138bdd6b2f805fe641da3d149f720ea4817a784c9fdbb95c7e9f.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want the texture to be stretched by the vertices edit, enable the options called *Correct Faces Attribute* (since 2.9):

[image]
[image]

Also if you slide some edge loops (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) make sure that you've enabled the *Correct UVs* option in the Operator box (it should be by default):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick!